# Does ruby open-uri HTTP Streaming throttle the download or save to a temp file?

Tags: ruby, open-uri

I have a large CSV file on a server I'd like to download and process in chunks, without reading the whole thing into memory. After a bit of finagling I've come up with this:

```
require open-uri

open("http://example.com/#{LARGE_CSV_FILE}") do |file|
  file.each_slice(50_000) do |fifty_thousand_lines|
    MyModel.import fifty_thousand_lines.join
  end
end
```

My understanding is that `open-uri`'s `#open` will wrap the HTTP GET and return an `IO`-like enumerable object. `#each_slice(n)` will pass the block an array of n lines at a time. I then join and process those lines.

This imports just fine, and watching my OS X iStat menu, it looks like the memory usage of the ruby process doesn't get out of hand. **However**, it looks like I downloaded all of the file at once. How can this be without the memory usage exploding?

Does ruby download it to a temporary file and then read it from disk line by line? I would have thought `open-uri` would instead throttle the HTTP connection and only download more data when its block has finished processing its batch of data.

Is this the right way of downloading and processing a file without loading it all into memory?

Comment: Take a look: [fseventer.app](http://fernlightning.com/doku.php?id=software%3afseventer%3astart) will show you files accessed by a process.  `lsof` may too, but you'd need to catch it while the file is open.  Another API to try would be `Net::HTTP`, its read method [returns segments of a file](http://www.dotnetguy.co.uk/post/2011/09/27/large-ruby-file-downloads-done-right/).  Might have to do some buffering yourself to make sure you get full lines since it's a CSV though.

Comment: Ah, thanks for the heads up on fseventer, Nick. Fired it up and ran my script. That did the trick. Looks like `open-uri` downloads to a temp file, and then reads from there.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it does download to a tempfile. This is easily observed from the console:

```
2.0.0-p247 :001 > require 'open-uri'
 => true
2.0.0-p247 :002 > f = open("http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19279715/does-ruby-open-uri-http-streaming-throttle-the-download-or-save-to-a-temp-file")
 => #<Tempfile:/tmp/open-uri20140220-27172-1kcjwk2>
```

Comment: Here's the code in question. https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/v2_1_1/lib/open-uri.rb#L382-394

Comment: Not necessarily. If the size of the file is smaller than `StringMax` constant defined in library, instance of `StringIO` is returned instead of `Tempfile`.